# How to listen to press more buttons on the keyboard?

Tags: java, windows, keyboard, keylistener

I on the keyboard a lot more buttons, and I really need to listen to push the buttons (multimedia play, stop ..).

How do it?

And I would like to catch the event, even when the window is minimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this [jintellitype](http://melloware.com/products/jintellitype/index.html) to catch key events outside your app in Windows. 
Here is for linux [JXGrabKey](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jxgrabkey/)

Update: to use multimedia buttons, you need to know it's codes. Add this listener to your app's frame to find out codes:

```
class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter {
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
    System.out.println("Key code: " + evt.getKeyCode());       
  }
}
```

If you will know the code, just check if evt.getKeyCode() is what you need and make some actions.